# Segmentation fault (core dumped) programming in C

Tags: c

I was solving the HackerRank problem given here : -- https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bigger-is-greater

Program statement is as follow :

> Given a word, rearrange the letters to construct another word in such a way that is lexicographically greater than original one. In case of multiple possible answers, find the lexicographically smallest one among them.

If you don't understand then just go to the link; they have explained with examples.

I made the program as given below. In this program I have made two dimensional array. And variable `t` decides number of row and number is fix.

Code is running as it should be when `t = 1`.
But when t is greater than 1 or some large number it gives error **segmentation error**

Code is as below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int i,j,n,rot;
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char c[t][100];
    char temp;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %s",c[i]);
    }
    rot=t;
    for(int t=0;t<rot;t++)
    {
        n  = strlen(c[t]);
        //printf("%d\n",n);
        for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                //printf("comparint %c and %c\n",c[t][i],c[t][j]);   //FOR DEBUG
                if(c[t][i]>c[t][j]) goto gotit;
            }
        }
        printf("no answer\n");

        continue;

    gotit:
        temp = c[t][i];
        c[t][i]=c[t][j];
        c[t][j]=temp;
        n = (n-1)-j;
        //printf("%s\n",c[t]);  //FOR DEBUG
        //printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,n); //FOR DEBUG

        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<n-1;k++)
            {
                //  printf("comparint %c and %c\n",c[t][j+k+1],c[t][j+k+2]);
                if(c[t][j+k+1]>c[t][j+k+2] )
                {
                    temp = c[t][j+k+1];
                    c[t][j+k+1]=c[t][j+k+2];
                    c[t][j+k+2]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n",c[t]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start simple - fix your indentation.

Comment: If I could solve this problem, I would submit it directly to Hacker Rank, but thanks for the opportunity to be your proxy. Those sites are about *your* abilities.

Comment: What line is the segmentation fault happening on? You should try stepping through the program with a debugger, examining the values of your strings at various steps to see when they've become corrupted.

Comment: When harkening back to hackerrank, consider this: Do you really, *really* need an array of char array ? Once know the number of test cases, isn't the actual handling of each case independent of all the others? Why bother storing all those strings when you can just handle them one at a time *as you read them* ? If anything it would declutter your code significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` can be `10^5` or 100,000. Your `c` array is `c[t][100]`, so the size of that is `100000 * 100`, which is 10,000,000. You're probably getting a stack overflow.

As WhozCraig pointed out, the processing of each case is independent. Thus, `c` can be a one dimensional array: `char c[100]`. Change all `c[t][...]` into `c[...]`.

Adjust things so that you have one outer loop:

```
int
main()
{
    int t;
    char c[100];

    scanf("%d", &t);

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf(" %s", c);
        // do all processing for this line ...
        n = strlen(c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```